# can you explain to me what does that mean $R_n=f^{(n)}(c)(b-a)^n/n!$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm reading a book about calculus, and in the chapter of **Taylor Series** when the author tried to estimate the remainder term he started by saying this:

> In Taylor's Formula there exists a number $c$ in the interval $[a,b]$ such that the remainder term is given by $$R_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)(b-a)^n}{n!}$$

Where $[a,b]$ is the interval in which the function is continuous and has $n$ derivatives

Where does this come from? And what does it mean?

Comment: This is the Lagrange form of the remainder term of Taylor's formula. One of the usual proofs of Taylor's formula yields this form for the remainder.

Comment: [Derivation for the mean value forms of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder)

Comment: is that related to the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes, it is the mean value form of the remainder which can be derived with the help of the mean value theorem.